# Fetching Facebook posts into Hdfs

Tags: hadoop, flume

How to retrieve facebook user post into hdfs, is there any process for saving post into hdfs. I have gone through the twitter analysis using flume. Does facebook user posts can also retrieve in the same way ??

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has lot of restrictions when compared to twitter.
Earlier i used Informatica to pull some posts and group posts.
We cannot pull the posts of others or their personal data.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/

Comment: Thanks  for answer, is there any way to pull a page posts/comments into hdfs using graph api ??